# can i use bluetooth from a speaker as a bluetooth module?

Tags: bluetooth, speaker

**i have a Bluetooth speakers that i don't want,and i was wondering if i can use its Bluetooth as a Bluetooth module to use it with Arduino.
if so how what pins should i use. here is a pin diagram for the module.**

[image: pin diagram of the bluetooth module]

Comment: it is a bluetooth module ... you could monitor the state of the rx and tx pins

Comment: i don't know which pins to use

Comment: there is a pad labeled RXD1 and a pad labeled TXD1... use those ... see if the voltage on them changes

Comment: where did you get the pictures?

Comment: i got them from a Chinese pdf when i was looking for information

Comment: what other information was in the pdf?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/10mo3RCH8rkPNug8zLBfqPJ4xnyeFZ0ff/view?usp=sharing                           https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c6PKiCihaJIQ_E5oNBttr-Y1TXne45p2/view?usp=sharing  but they are chinese

Comment: In principle you can use it with an Arduino, though that really depends on what you want to do with it. You didn't explain that.

Comment: That is a common bluetooth audio receiver that has been used with Arduino in the past (I recall seeing a question here recently about controlling the volume of one with an Arduino), but only for audio separate to the Arduino. What do you think you might want to use it for? It receives audio and outputs it through its speaker pins. The main chip may be programmable, but good luck getting information on that, or a toolchain to do it.

Comment: I thinks those modules are for audio (A2DP) only. Do you want to use it to create a UART (Serial) connection over bluetooth?

Comment: You say "i was wondering if i can use its Bluetooth as a Bluetooth module to use it with Arduino." What do you want to do with it, exactly? Edit your question to be more specific. Play music over Bluetooth? (answer probably = yes.) Serial Bluetooth communications? (answer probably = no)

Comment: sorry for the late reply but this is all i wanted :D "Serial Bluetooth communications? (answer probably = no)". big thanks to everyone tryed to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth actually uses many different protocols to support many different Bluetooth applications.  For 2 channel good fidelity music with high latency and a very low bandwidth return only suitable for short infrequent commands like PAUSE and PLAY, most use [A2DP or Advanced Audio Distribution Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Advanced_Audio_Distribution_Profile_(A2DP)).

As most Arduino platforms use very low powered processors, good fidelity sound manipulation is not possible or is very difficult.  This only leaves the very low bandwidth return channel only suitable for short infrequent commands.  If you can imagine a use case for this channel it may be possible to use a low powered Arduino to send these PAUSE, PLAY, STOP type commands.

That said, you may want to buy a new well supported (in the Arduino community) Bluetooth module which uses the [HID (Human Interface Device) protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Human_Interface_Device_Profile_(HID)) so you can build a keyboard for example or which uses the [SPP (Serial Port Profile) protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Serial_Port_Profile_(SPP)) so you can build something that sends arbitrary data.

Added later...

I see in the diagram that there may be an "microphone in pin".  If true this hints that the module also supports the Bluetooth [HFP (Hands Free Profile) protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Hands-Free_Profile_(HFP)).  This is a lower fidelity 2 directional low latency audio channel with a very low bandwidth return only suitable for short infrequent commands like ANSWER and HANGUP.  Instead of music this is used to make phone calls.  This might be of more interest to Arduino project builders as this might be made into an intercom.